# View R-tree hierarchy of a R-tree index

Tags: postgis, postgresql, rtree

Is there a tool that can help us visualize the R-tree structure of an index in PostgreSQL? I am using OSM data and want to see the hierarchy as in which are the root nodes and and which are the children of that root. I came across Gevel ([http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/oddmuse/index.cgi/Gevel](http://www.sai.msu.su/%7Emegera/oddmuse/index.cgi/Gevel)) tool, but it did not work for the current version, and also could not get any response from the authors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fork of Gevel which works with more recent versions at https://github.com/pramsey/gevel